# To display a record having multiple values in a table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, insertion

Desired output-

```
Emp_name|Hobbies|age|DOB
______________________________
LOPEZ        |Football , Swimming , Fishing |19| 1999-05-11
```

Here in the question, the Hobbies column is having multiple records with comma separate, BUT I want in a SINGLE line (Vertically).
All the records for hobbies should be a single record, like multiple values in single record. 
And, last display in one row.

Please help me creating a table and way to insert and fetch the record in postgres DB.

Comment: I don't recommend a comma separated list (nor an array (Hint!)). Have a persons table, a hobbies table and another table that links the hobbies to a person. Also the age shouldn't be stored in the persons table, as it is obviously dependent on the birthday an the current time. But apart from that: What have you got so far and what is the exact problem with what you have so far. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: So can you help me creating a table like this and fetch the record in the similar manner which I explained. All the HOBBIES values should be together. My is desired result is not that complex. Hobbies have multiple values. How to insert and fetch it together.

Answer (score 0):

So we want to reformat your 'hobbies' string to an array. You can use the     ARRAY_AGG() function:

```
    CREATE TABLE new_hobbies AS
    SELECT
        name 
        , age 
        , DOB 
        , ARRAY_AGG(hobbies) AS hobbies
    FROM table
    GROUP BY
        name
        , age
        , dob
```

But yeah I agree with sticky bit's answer that normalisation of this single table would be a good idea. As well as not having an age value - to avoid issues with updates.

Comment: So can you help me creating a table like this and fetch the record in the similar manner which I explained. All the HOBBIES values should be together. My is desired result is not that complex. Hobbies have multiple values. How to insert and fetch it together.

Comment: Can you help me inserting some values in the new_hobbies table? How shall i insert values in the array column?

Comment: Thanks a lot Rupert. I got the result as expected. I would be very helpful if you can help me represent the output as below :-
`                                    name                                  | age |    dob     |          hobbies
------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+------------+----------------------------
 Rocky                                                                  |  27   | 1991-04-17    | Fishing |
                  |     |           | Cricket |
                  |     |            | Football  |`

Comment: I mean to say that the values should represent in vertical wise rather than comma separated. Can you help me in this? @Rupert